# What is the correct syntax to dynamically add checkbox items to a list in jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have been successful in adding list items of `<li>` to a unordered list `ul`. But now it seems I am having trouble adding checkbox items to a list which is within one `<li>`.  In my jsfiddle below

1. I empty the list
2. Append to the list
3. Refresh the list to add the jqm class styles

Again this has worked in the past for adding list items to a list.I am sure my syntax is just wrong.

http://jsfiddle.net/N7Z9e/1112/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
$("#ulTest").listview("refresh")
```

Should change to:

```
$("#ulTest").listview("refresh").find('input').checkboxradio();
```

You have to initialize any widget that you add dynamically. Basically you're telling jQuery Mobile that you have added a widget and you want it to be styled. You were updating the `listview` widget but not initializing the new `checkbox` widgets.

Docs: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0-rc.1/docs/forms/checkboxes/methods.html

Here is an updated version of your JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/N7Z9e/1113/

Answer (score 0):

Switch the binding method to just `.click`

```
$('#btnTest').click(function(e){
});
```

Comment: Yes that does fix the button event. I just put it there for this demo purposes. However, the real question is how to get newly inserted checkbox item styled with the jQuery classes.